# Using a computed property from a vuex getter in a module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-bash-61mfo

I´m working with the rootState all the time, but I need find the actual element across all the elements with it´s id, so I created parentItem for this.

There are any way to access to `parentItem` in the `myProperties` getter?? I need this to later use mutations and actions across this getter to change the rootState parent item.

If I use the [Method-Style Access](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access) I have to put it in the `alert.js` store and I cannot have access to the `parentItem` computed property…

Besides, in every other getter/action/mutation should send the ID to pass again to the correct getter to obtain the parentItem, when I already have the id thanks to the props…

Any idea how can accomplish this?

I can change all the structure if it´s required, but I don´t find any better way to structure the data...

Comment: Can you please explain it as i am unable to get your problem?

Comment: I updated the demo. Imagine I have a button to change a property from the parent element, `randomMessage` in this case. I need a way to find the element in the root components array and then change the property